# Order based on inheritance in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, ontology

I have a dataframe of information on an ontology like the following sample:

```
onto<- data.frame(entity = c('disease', 'neurologic disease', 'heart disease', 'lung disease', 'kidney disease', 'gastrointestinal disease', 'seizure', 'iatrogenic seizure', 'cardiomyopathy', 'hypertrophic cardiomyopathy', 'restrictive cardiomyopathy', 'kidney stone', 'glomerulonephritis', 'proliferative gn', 'nonproliferative gn', 'rpgn', 'vasculitic rpgn', 'good pasture', 'wegeners', 'diarrhea', 'asthma', 'pneumonia'), superclass = c('owl:thing', 'disease', 'disease', 'disease', 'disease', 'disease', 'neurologic disease', 'seizure', 'heart disease', 'cardiomyopathy', 'cardiomyopathy', 'kidney disease', 'kidney disease', 'glomerulonephritis', 'glomerulonephritis', 'proliferative gn', 'rpgn', 'rpgn', 'vasculitic rpgn', 'gastrointestinal disease', 'lung disease', 'lung disease'))
```

I need to order these entities (dataframe rows) based on the following conditions:

A. for the first level I don't want alphabetical order. instead I want to determine the order myself. for example I want the list of diseases to be shown in the following order: 1- 'neurologic disease', 2- 'heart disease', 3-'kidney disease', 4-'lung disease',5- 'gastrointestinal disease'

B. for other levels I just want the entities sorted based on inheritance:
for example : 'proliferative gn'>> 'rpgn'>> 'vasculitic rpgn'>> 'good pasture'>> 'wegeners' (*of course it is not always as straightforward as this*)

note: Item B is more important to me.

I'm grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, what do you mean by the levels here? Like the first level and other levels, you've mentioned. The first 5 will always stay on the top and the others will come after them in the order?

Comment: i mean disease is the first level... neurologic disorder and heart disorder and all direct subclasses of disease are second level .... all direct subclasses of the above are third level and so forth...

Comment: Read about factors. Set your columns as factor with your own order, then it will be sorted accordingly.

Comment: @zx8754   This would be a huge task... I want them sorted by superclass. with subclasses of each entity in the row below it.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb   you can see what i mean by level here [https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Traversing-the-Ontology-Tree_fig3_4309847   if this were my ontology i would want the rows as follows characteristic... feeling... positive feeling ... mild... smile .. moderate... strong.. happy... proud... intense... negative feeling

Answer (score 2):

What your inheritance rules imply is a directed graph, giving a partial order to the rows.  To put those in a consistent order you need what's called a "topological sort" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort).  There are several functions in R packages that can do this.  I haven't used any of them, so I don't know which is best/easiest:  `igraph::topo_sort()`, `Rfast::topological_sort()`, `ggm::topSort()`. `HEMDAG::lexicographical.topological.sort()`.

I suspect the biggest difference between these is how you manipulate your data to produce appropriate input.

I find it a little unclear what the relation should be between your rules A and B.  Maybe it's as simple as adding some relations like `'neurologic disease < 'heart disease' < 'kidney disease' < 'lung disease' < 'gastrointestinal disease'` to your partial order.  (Or maybe I have the direction backwards.)